# HTML Login Page shows creds in page source

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Okay, So I am trying to make a private website for a group of my friends to have access to, no one else can register, or log in. My script is...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Login page
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;text-align="center";font-size:20pt;
color:#00FF00;>
Simple Login Page
</h1>
<form name="login">
Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
<input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
{
 /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
 if(form.userid.value == "myuserid" && form.pswrd.value == "mypswrd")
  {
    window.open('target.html')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
  }
 else
 {
   alert("Error Password or Username")/*displays error message*/
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Using that code, someone could open the page source code, and view the creds. Is there a way I can hide and encrypt it, and maybe add a few different accounts?

Comment: make server side validation

Comment: Yes. And with just HTML and JavaScript, no.

Comment: everything on the client-side can be viewed by any user, that's just how the web works. (You could obfuscate your Javascript code, but that does not constitute proper security,) Anything secret needs to be done on the server side.

Comment: Oh God, no...`font-family:Comic Sans`

Comment: @j08691 Shhhhhhhhh, You dont see anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you write in client-side JavaScript has the potential to be seen by others in their browser, for that reason, things like authentication should be handled on the server.

It's also important to know that you should never store passwords in plain-text.

Another important thing I can see from reading your code is that I could probably just navigate to https://whatever.com/target.html and see the page you are trying to protect with a password.

If you're interested in building a site with this kind of feature, you will need to use a server-side language and write some code for the server.

Comment: Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: Yes, you should look into some server-side languages and possibly a framework. For the kind of thing you're trying to do PHP might be a good place to start. If you're already familiar with JavaScript you could look into Node. My personal choice for something this small would be Python with Flask, however there are no wrong choices.

Comment: I use node actually, that’s what I am running it through, I just don’t know where to store the accounts.

Comment: I'm not much of a Node developer, but this seems like a good tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYjHDMPrkWU

Answer (score 1):

You should never put sensitive information in client-side code since it would be visible for anyone who views page source or inspect element. The only things you should validate on client side are stuff like required fields or is valid email and so on. Then in the server side script you do the sensitive validations like the ones you have done above. Also i must point out that checking a user using an if statement is extremely bad practice. You should work on the server side logic of your app more.

Comment: My question, is how can I do that?

Comment: @DerekHaber you need to use a server side language like PHP or asp.net or nodeJs... and integrate it with your current client-side code. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @DerekHaber the server side handles everything from storing forms to authentication. So i really advise you choose a language and go into it. PHP is a relatively easy language to start with and integrate with existing html and javascript.

Comment: @DerekHaber honestly there are many very useful php tutorials about how to make a good safe login and session system. They usually walk you through it step by step. Its not an easy thing to answer on stack overflow as it has many steps.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way to do a server side authentification, is my making a basic HTTP Auth, using an .htaccess and a .htpasswd file.